# Colspan Width Issue for Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I'm having trouble getting Outloook 2013 to render this code correctly. I'm trying to get the two columns next to each other in a 600px table in the 2nd row. 
For some reason, the first column in the second row is spanning 600px and the second column is correctly to the right but is just tacked on in addition to the 600px so it spans larger than the rest of the columns.

Here is the jsfiddle of the code (sorry for the long code). https://jsfiddle.net/abdiyohan/hdpjjh5x/2/

```
<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
```

```
<table align="center" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;" align="center">
            <table style="width:600px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="border-top: 7px solid #a0a5a6; border-bottom: 2px solid #a0a5a6; color: #000000;width:100%;" bgcolor="#005195" height="95" width="100%">
                        <img align="top" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 18px;border-style: none;color: #ffffff;" alt="" src="" height="95" width="600" border="0" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="75%" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #a0a5a6;padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #e83e2a; width:75%;font-size: 14pt; line-height: 28px;" valign="top" align="left">
                        <div width="100%" style="width:100%;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#005195;padding-bottom:0px; font-size: 14pt; line-height: 28px;"><a name="English">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                            <p style="line-height: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0px; font-size: 11pt;padding-top:10px;color:#005195;">Lorem Ipsum,</p>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="display:block;margin:0px 20px 20px 0;" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="28" style="height:28px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background:#ccc; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0px 10px; color: #005195;" align="left">
                                        <div align="center"><a style="color: #005195; text-decoration: none;" href="#top" target="_self">Back to Top</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #a0a5a6;background-color:#efefef;padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#005195; width:25%; font-size: 14pt; line-height: 28px;" align="right" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top" width="25%">
                        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;" width="100%">
                             <h1 style="font-size: 14pt;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#005195;font-weight:normal;padding:0px;margin:0px;">Global Links</h1>

                            <p style="color:#4682B4;font-size: 11pt; line-height: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top:10px;"><a style="color:#4682B4; text-decoration: none;" href="#English" target="_self">English</a>
                            </p>
                            <p style="color:#4682B4;font-size: 11pt; line-height: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"><a style="color:#4682B4; text-decoration: none;" href="#Spanish (Latin America)" target="_self">Español (Latinoamérica)</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" width="100%" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #a0a5a6;padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #e83e2a; width: 100%;font-size: 14pt; line-height: 28px;" valign="top" align="left">
                        <div width="100%" style="width:100%;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#005195;padding-bottom:0px; font-size: 14pt; line-height: 28px;"> <a name="Spanish (Latin America)"></a>¡Comparta su opinión!
                            <p style="line-height: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0px; font-size: 11pt;padding-top:10px;color:#005195;">Lorem Ipsum,</p>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="display:block;margin:0px 20px 20px 0;" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="28" style="height:28px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background:#ccc; border-radius: 5px; padding: 0px 10px; color: #005195;" align="left">
                                        <div align="center"><a style="color: #005195; text-decoration: none;" href="#top" target="_self">Back to Top</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know the code looks pretty messy, but I've tried so many solutions and fixes from across the internet and have come up with nothing.

This code works in OWA, which is strange and depressing, but breaks in Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2011 for Mac. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup. You can find the supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties described in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: According to that page, td tags and colspan is fully supported. It doesn't quite help with the issue at hand. Also, are there difference between 2007 and 2013? Not 100% sure on that.